# Prove that three points are collinear (Menelaus theorem?)

Tags: geometry

Given a point P inside the triangle ABC. Lines AP, BP, CP intersect the sides BC, CA, AB in points $A_1, B_1, C_1$. The lines $A_1B_1$ and AB intersect in the point  $A_2$. The points $B_2,C_2$ are defined in a similar way. How can I prove that $A_2, B_2, C_2$ are collinear?
I think it has to do someting with the Menelaus theorem. But how can I use it here?. Another hard thing in this task is that it is almost impossible to draw a good figure, the best thing I could get is that:
[image: Figure]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva's_theorem) for the cevians through $P\,$:

$$
\frac{BA_1}{A_1C}\cdot\frac{CB_1}{B_1A}\cdot\frac{AC_1}{C_1B} = 1
\tag{1}$$

By [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus'_theorem) for the transversal $A_1B_1\,$:

$$
\frac{BA_2}{A_2A}\cdot\frac{AB_1}{B_1C}\cdot\frac{CA_1}{A_1B} = -1
\tag{2}
$$

Multiplying the two $(1) \cdot (2)\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\cancel{\frac{BA_1}{A_1C}}\cdot\bcancel{\frac{CB_1}{B_1A}}\cdot\frac{AC_1}{C_1B} \;\cdot\; \frac{BA_2}{A_2A}\cdot\bcancel{\frac{AB_1}{B_1C}}\cdot\cancel{\frac{CA_1}{A_1B}} = -1 \;\;\iff\;\; \frac{BA_2}{A_2A} = -\,\frac{C_1B}{AC_1}
$$

Repeat for $B_2,C_2\,$, multiply together, and the RHS reduces to $-1$ using $(1)$ one more time.

(*It should be noted that the problem is equivalent to half the [Desargues' theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Desargues.shtml) in the plane*.)

Comment: And what happens when we get all those -1s?

Comment: @idliketodothis It follows that $A_2,B_2,C_2$ are collinear by (the converse of) Menelaus' theorem.

Comment: But what I got for point B2 is B2C/B2B = -BA1/A1C; for point C1: AC2/CC2 = -B1A/CB1;
All in all, I have C1B/AC1 * BA1/A1C * B1A/CB1 = -1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @idliketodothis Don't know how you somehow reverted to $(1)\,$. What you get in fact is $BA_2/A_2A \cdot AC_2/C_2C \cdot CB_2 / B_2B = -1\,$, which proves that $A_2,B_2,C_2$ are collinear. As a side note, you did not choose the best notation to preserve the symmetry in $A,B,C\,$, and it would have been easier to follow had you defined $AB \cap A_1B_1=C'$ instead of $A_2\,$.

Answer (score 0):

**A proof using projective geometry**: Triangles $ABC$ and $A_1B_1C_1$ are perspective from the point $P$, so by Desargues' Theorem they are perspective from a line too, i.e. their pairs of corresponding sides intersect at $3$ points which are collinear. This implies $A_2,B_2,C_2$ are collinear.